# How to carve out exceptions in Kubernetes RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Use-cases:

- Grant full access to all resources on the cluster (including the ability to e.g. create new namespaces), except for in certain namespaces such as `kube-system`.
- Grant read permissions to all resources in the cluster except for Secrets.

This seems like a really basic set of use-cases that are not obvious how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Grant read permissions to all resources in the cluster except for Secrets.

  kubectl get clusterrole view | grep -v secrets

fix the metadata creating a new ClusterRole. create ClusterRoleBindings using that ClusterRole.

- Grant full access to all resources ... except in certain namespaces

For this, you would need to create rolebindings in each namespace you want to delegate those privileges to, you won't be able to filter out namespaces by their name.

You could use the clusterrole "admin", and create rolebindings in all your projects. OpenShift would have some defaultProjectTemplate you could customize automatically adding those RoleBindings when provisioning a new namespace. While I don't think traditional Kubernetes have such an option: you might then use a CronJob, say in kube-system, creating those RoleBindings into new namespaces on a schedule.

Comment: WRT the secrets question - that works nicely, thank you.

Comment: WRT the namespace question, that's wild that such a basic use-case isn't handled natively.  We'll have to think of other ways to harden the dev cluster a bit since what you propose is pretty significant engineering for a non-production environment.  I just don't want accidental deletion of coredns or such.

Comment: FYI, I could have also suggested: using of home-grown controllers (operator framework, or whatever feels easier for you to maintain). This is relatively common, with OpenShift customers, to see custom controllers implementing security requirements when Kubernetes or OpenShift don't provide a satisfying default.